# inner product identity and property

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

This came up in a proof in my text:
[image]

I am unable to understand how the connection between the last equality came about.

Any explanation would be helpful

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $e_1$ is the usual standard basis vector, then $\langle e_1, e_1\rangle=||e_1||^2=1$.

Comment: @AnuragA Can you expand on that? How were you able to arrive at the inner produce of $e_{1}$?

Comment: By inner product linearity